# Sendmail configuration on AlmaLinux

Tags: linux, sendmail

I am trying to setup an sendmail server with email domain xeonbridge.com. So any user account I create in Linux, should be username.xeonbridge.com, right?

*Sendmail.mc* is configured with lines (only changed to suit my setup):

- define(`SMART_HOST',` smtp-GreenSpace.xeonbridge.com')dnl
- DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Port=smtp, Addr=127.0.0.1, Name=MSA, M=Ea')dnl

File */etc/mail/local-host-names* is configured with:

- GreenSpace.xeonbridge.com

And finally my hostname is set with GreenSpace

When I check mail, I see *from* logs of netuser@GreenSpace?

Can anyone see where my configuration is wrong as it should be outputting netuser@xeonbridge.com?

Thanks